# New UITabbar on specific UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following problem:
I have a UITableView with Core Data objects. When I click on one UITableViewCell it shows a detail view controller via pushViewController. Now I want to have on the detail view controller a UITabBar to manage the date easily. On the first UITableView I have also a UITabBar.
How can I manage that? Can you please help me? :)

**EDIT:**
*Here is my viewDidLoad:*

```
viewDidLoad()
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    UITabBar *newTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 367.0, 320.0, 49.0)];
    [newTabBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self]];
    [[self view] addSubview:newTabBar];
}
```

*And my detail view controller when it's pushed:*

```
...

detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
[detailViewController setManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

...
```

*And finally the error:*

```
-[DetailViewController _updateView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a3c190
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController _updateView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a3c190'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a `UITabBarController` on the first tableView, then set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`to `YES`on your view controller. On the detail view controller, embed a plain `UITabBar` without controller and do the appropriate actions in your `UITabBarDelegate`.

The reason is, a `UITabBarController` always wants to be at the root of the stack and not to be embedded in a different view controller.

Comment: I initialize and add the UITabBar to the UIViewController in the viewDidLoad of the detail view controller. But when I call [tabBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self]] I get an error. How can I add items?

Comment: `[newTabBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self]];` is wrong because it requires an array of `UITabBarItem` whereas you're giving it an array of `UIViewController`.